# getting wrong item in custom ListView Adapter

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-listview, listview-adapter

i have a custom adapter for ListView
the getView method is something like this :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        //final ILSpeechBubble speechBubble;

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            if(m_msg.get(position).Recieved == 0)
            {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_message_sent_row_template, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.spBubble = (ILSpeechBubble) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iLSpeechBubble1);

                holder.imgProfilePic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);
                holder.imgSend = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgMessageSent);

                holder.imgDeliverd = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgMessageDeliverd);
                holder.pbSending = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pbSendingMessage);

                holder.spBubble.isChache = false;
                holder.Position = position;
                convertView.setTag(holder);
                m_ViewHolder.add(holder);
            }
            else
            {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_message_recieved_row_template, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.spBubble = (ILSpeechBubble) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iLSpeechBubble1);
                holder.imgProfilePic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);
                holder.spBubble.isChache = false;
                holder.Position = position;
                convertView.setTag(holder);
                m_ViewHolder.add(holder);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            if(holder.Position == position)
                Log.i("View Holder","Position : " + position);
            Log.i("View Holder","Position : " + position + " Wrong");
            Log.i("View Holder","Position : " + holder.Position + " HolderPos");
            //position = holder.Position;
            holder = findHolder(position);
            if(holder == null)
            {
                if(m_msg.get(position).Recieved == 0)
                {
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_message_sent_row_template, null);

                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.spBubble = (ILSpeechBubble) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iLSpeechBubble1);

                    holder.imgProfilePic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);
                    holder.imgSend = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgMessageSent);

                    holder.imgDeliverd = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgMessageDeliverd);
                    holder.pbSending = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pbSendingMessage);

                    holder.spBubble.isChache = false;
                    holder.Position = position;
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                    m_ViewHolder.add(holder);
                }
                else
                {
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_message_recieved_row_template, null);

                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.spBubble = (ILSpeechBubble) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iLSpeechBubble1);
                    holder.imgProfilePic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);
                    holder.spBubble.isChache = false;
                    holder.Position = position;
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                    m_ViewHolder.add(holder);
                }
            }

            Log.i("View Holder","Position After Find : " + position + " Wrong");
            Log.i("View Holder","Position After Find : " + holder.Position + " HolderPos");

            holder.spBubble.isChache = true;

            //return v;
        }

        if(m_msg.get(position).Recieved == 0)
        {
            holder.spBubble.setBubbleDirectionLeft(false);
            //speechBubble.setBubbleDirectionLeft(false);
            holder.spBubble.setTextAlign(Align.RIGHT);

            if (m_msg.get(position).Deliverd == 1)
            {
                holder.imgDeliverd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.imgDeliverd.setImageResource(R.drawable.message_deliverd);
                holder.imgSend.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.pbSending.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else if (m_msg.get(position).Sent == 1)
            {
                holder.imgDeliverd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.imgSend.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.imgSend.setImageResource(R.drawable.message_sent);
                holder.pbSending.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            holder.spBubble.setBubbleDirectionLeft(true);
            holder.spBubble.setTextAlign(Align.RIGHT);
        }

        CContacts_Info contact = cl_ContactInfo.GetContact(m_ContactILId);

        holder.spBubble.setMessageBody(m_msg.get(position).MessageBody);

        if(m_msg.get(position).MessageType.equals(AttachType.Emoji.name()))
            holder.spBubble.setEmojiList(m_EmojiList);
        else if(m_msg.get(position).MessageType.equals(AttachType.Picture.name()))
        {
            holder.spBubble.setImageSize(128, 128);
            holder.spBubble.setImageReadyState(m_msgList.get(position).isImageReady);
            if(m_msgList.get(position).isImageReady)
                holder.spBubble.setPictureMessageThumbPic(m_msgList.get(position).ThumbPic);
        }

        holder.spBubble.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.spBubble.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        holder.spBubble.setFontSize(m_Default_FontSize);

        holder.spBubble.setMessageId(m_msg.get(position)._id);

        if (m_msg.get(position)._id == iMessageId)
        {
            if (m_msg.get(position).iProgressValue == 100)
                m_Downloading = false;
            else
                m_msg.get(position).iProgressValue += 10;

            holder.spBubble.SetProgress(m_msg.get(position).iProgressValue);
        }
        else
            holder.spBubble.SetProgress(100);

        //ImageView imgProfilePic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);
        //holder.imgProfilePic.setPadding(0, holder.spBubble.getHeight(), 0, 0);

        if(contact.ProfilePic != null)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(contact.ProfilePic, 0,
                    contact.ProfilePic.length,m_BitmapOPT);

            holder.imgProfilePic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        else
        {
            holder.imgProfilePic.setImageResource(R.drawable.profile_pic);
        }

        if (m_isStop)
        {
            holder.spBubble.setVoiceMessage_Play(false);
            holder.spBubble.invalidate();
            m_isStop = false;
        }

        if (m_Playing)
            UpdateTimer(holder.spBubble);

        // UpdateTimer(holder.spBubble);

        holder.spBubble.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                String messageType = m_msg.get(holder.Position).MessageType;
                if (messageType.equals(AttachType.VoiceMessage.name()))
                {
                    if (m_Playing)
                    {
                        stopPlaying();

                        holder.spBubble.setVoiceMessage_Play(false);
                        holder.spBubble.invalidate();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        String source = holder.spBubble.getAttachSource();
                        // Toast.makeText(Message_Activity.this, source,
                        // 1000).show();

                        startPlaying(source);
                        ShowNotify(R.string.VoiceMessage_Play_Title);

                        update_Timer.run();

                    }
                }
                else if (messageType.equals(AttachType.Audio.name()))
                {
                    if (holder.spBubble.getProgress() < 100)
                        return;
                    String source = holder.spBubble.getAttachSource();
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    File file = new File(source);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else if (messageType.equals(AttachType.Video.name()))
                {
                    if (holder.spBubble.getProgress() < 100)
                        return;
                    String source = holder.spBubble.getAttachSource();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(source), "video/*");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else if (messageType.equals(AttachType.Picture.name()))
                {
                    String source = holder.spBubble.getAttachSource();
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///" + source), "image/*");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }   
            }
        });

        holder.spBubble.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v)
            {

                List<Action_Type> actionList = CreatePopUpMenuList_Message(m_msg.get(holder.Position)._id);
                ListView lstPopUpAction = (ListView) m_PopUpDialog.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

                lstPopUpAction.setAdapter(new Show_Action_Adapter(Message_Activity.this,
                        actionList));

                m_PopUpDialog.show();
                return true;
            }
        });

        holder.spBubble.invalidate();

        //convertView.setTag(holder);

        return convertView;
    }
```

but the item that showing in listView after scroll is wrong,sometimes duplicate item and sometimes wrong order to showing list item.
i set the value of item after if/else to getting view but the problem not solved!
if i create view again and not use to caching convertView (means :

> if(convertView == null

the item is showing correctly,but if scroll to much the app crash for getting too much memory.
i'm totally confused and don't know how can i solve it.

Comment: It's because of ListView Recycling :

[How ListView Recycling Works][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works

Comment: @Arash i cant get solution from mention link,can you explain how can i resolve this?

Comment: can you post your whole adapter or at least your getview()?

Comment: @Arash i updated my getView code,sorry to complexity

Answer (score 0):

Try instantiating your holder class inside of your getView(i can't see where you are instantiating that)

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
```

then make sure that your ViewHolder Class's static and also check your getCount() method to return your proper List Size.

Comment: i instantiate my holder in my adapter,out of getView